# Change message for waiting before accepting your own answer

Tags: feature-request

I posted a question and the comments were basically that what I was asking for was impossible or bad practice (invalid XML). So after a bit more digging I found the solution I was after (my XML was valid after all) and answered my own question. Since no-one else had posted an answer, only comments on my question, I wanted to immediately accept my own answer. A message popped up telling me to wait for 1 hour (I can't remember the exact wording). So I waited for an hour, tried again and this time the message said to wait for 56 minutes. It seems that you actually have to wait for 2 hours before you can accept your own answer but a time of "1:59:59" gets rounded down to "1:00:00". If someone asked me "when is the next train" and it was due in 1:59:59 from now I'd tell them "two hours" or "just under two hours" if I wanted to be precise. Can the pop-up message be reworded to convey more meaningful information please?